# Clear the App memory / Unregister services / re-login within the app

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I didn't know how to describe the Title, sorry about that.

I'm using .net Maui.
And the issue I'm facing is hard for me to explain, so I will add as much code as possible, In hope to fix this issue.

I have a login and logout pages.
When the app starts I'm using this code

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        var accountIdKey = Preferences.Get("AccountIdKey", string.Empty);
        var accountEmailKey = Preferences.Get("AccountEmailKey", string.Empty);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("FirebaseRefresher", "")) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIdKey))
        {
            var authToken = SecureStorage.GetAsync("AuthToken").Result;
            var firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper(accountEmailKey, authToken);

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LogInPage());
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LogInPage());
    }
}
```

and I register services like this (in MauiProgran.cs)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductList>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SettingsPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductListViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SettingsViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AccountViewModel>();
```

This is how I Login (AccountViewModel)

```
public class AccountViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    IAccountService accountService;
public string WebAPIKey = "my_web_api_key";
private string emailFromAuth;

public AccountViewModel()
{
}

public AccountViewModel(IAccountService accountService)
{
    this.accountService = accountService;
}

        public ICommand LogInCommand => new Command<Tuple<object, object>>(async (parameters) =>
        {
            string userEmailEntry = "";
            string userPasswordEntry = "";

            if (parameters != null && parameters.Item1 is Entry emailEntry && parameters.Item2 is Entry passwordEntry)
            {
                userEmailEntry = emailEntry.Text;
                userPasswordEntry = passwordEntry.Text;
            }

            var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebAPIKey));

            var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(userEmailEntry.ToLower(), userPasswordEntry);
            var emailVerified = auth.User.IsEmailVerified;

            if (emailVerified)
            {
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync("AuthToken", auth.FirebaseToken);

                var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://app-name.firebasedatabase.app/",
                  new FirebaseOptions
                  {
                      AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(auth.FirebaseToken)
                  });

                var userEmail = userEmailEntry.ToLower().Replace(".", "_");
                var userFromDB = await firebaseClient.Child(userEmail).Child("User").OnceSingleAsync<AccountProfile>();

                AccountProfile accountProfile = new();
                if (userFromDB == null)
                {
                    accountProfile = new AccountProfile
                    {
                        AccountId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        AccountEmail = userEmailEntry.ToLower()
                    };

                    await firebaseClient.Child(userEmail).Child("User").PutAsync(accountProfile);
                }

                else
                {
                    accountProfile.AccountId = userFromDB.AccountId;
                    accountProfile.AccountEmail = userFromDB.AccountEmail;
                }

                var firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper(accountProfile.AccountEmail, auth.FirebaseToken);

                var content = await auth.GetFreshAuthAsync();
                var serializedcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                Preferences.Set("FirebaseRefresher", serializedcontent);
                Preferences.Set("UserEmailKey", userEmailEntry.ToLower());

                App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
            }
            else { }
        });
}
```

and also, this is the FirebaseHelper

```
public class FirebaseHelper
{
private static FirebaseHelper instance = null;
public static FirebaseHelper Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new Exception("Null instance.");
        return instance;
    }
}

private string _accountEmail;
private string _authToken;
FirebaseClient firebaseClient;

public FirebaseHelper(string accountEmail, string authToken)
{
    _accountEmail = accountEmail.Replace(".", "_");
    _authToken = authToken;
    instance = this;

    firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://app-name.firebasedatabase.app",
    new FirebaseOptions
    {
        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(_authToken)
    });
}

public void ClearInstance()
{
    instance = null;
}

public async Task<List<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
{
    return (await firebaseClient.Child(_accountEmail).Child("Products")
      .OnceAsync<Product>()).Select(p => p.Object).ToList();
}
}
```

Since I included almost my whole project... this is how I get the list

```
public partial class ProductListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    readonly IProductService productService;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; } = new();

    public ProductListViewModel(IProductService productService)
    {
        this.productService = productService;
        (GetAllProductsCommand = new Command(async () => await GetAllProducts())).Execute(null);
    }

    public ICommand GetAllProductsCommand { get; }
    public async Task GetAllProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            var products = await productService.GetAllProductsAsync();

            if (ProductList.Count != 0)
                ProductList.Clear();

            ProductList.AddRange(products);
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

So... This is the complete way I'm logging in.

and this is my code to logout

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
public ICommand LogOutCommand => new Command(async () =>
{
    Preferences.Remove("AccountIdKey", string.Empty);
    Preferences.Remove("AccountEmailKey", string.Empty);

    try
    {
        Helper.FirebaseHelper.Instance.ClearInstance();
        Preferences.Remove("FirebaseRefresher");
    }
    catch { }

    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LogInPage());
});
}
```

Everything works almost great.
But, when I login, the app goes through (initialize) all the Viewmodels, FirebaseHelper etc...
and I get the `ProductList` by the login user (ill call it User1).

the problem is:
when I logout, it takes me to the "LogInPage" and if I'm logging in with different user (lets say User2), its still remembering User1 and its not going through (initialize) the Viewmodels, FirebaseHelper etc...
and its not updating the `ProductList` (it shows the `ProductList` of User1)
and also, on that code

```
public async Task<List<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
{
    return (await firebaseClient.Child(_accountEmail).Child("Products")
      .OnceAsync<Product>()).Select(p => p.Object).ToList();
}
```

the `"_accountEmail"` showing the User1 email instead of User2

and last thing, If I logout and restart the app... everything works good.

I know it's a very long story, I just didn't find any simple way to explain the issue.

Thank you so much.

Comment: the one thing that jumps out at me is that you are using `Preferences.Set("UserEmailKey"` but everywhere else you use `AccountEmailKey`.  Is that correct?  Otherwise the fastest way to solve this is to step through the code in the debugger and determine where it is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. its ture, the `Preferences.Set("UserEmailKey"` is used only once for something else. but anyway I removed that just in case, but its still the same

Comment: Then you need to use the debugger

Comment: May I ask how you update your viewmodels as you register all the service and viewmodel as singleton?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, I guess I'm not updating the viewmodels.
How do I do that? or if you need more code I can post whatever needed

Comment: I am not quite sure. Seems pages are reused. Have you tried AddTransient instead of AddSingleton?

Comment: @Liqun Shen-MSFT Thank you so much for guided me. I change it from `AddSingleton` to `AddTransient` and I changed from `private string _accountEmail;` to `private static string _accountEmail;`. it works now. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad you solved it! Yes, if changing to the AddTransient, the corresponding viewmodel will be recreated when navigating. By the way, I have added an answer below with more information hoping to help others with similar questions.  Please consider accepting it as answer if it is helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `AddSingleton<T>` in registration, that means a single instance of the object which will be remain for the lifetime of the application.

When using `AddTransient<T>` in registration, it Will create a new instance of the object when requested during resolution.

The **workaround** for this case is changing `AddSingleton<T>` to `AddTransient<T>`. Then the viewmodel registered will be recreated when you perform navigation.  Also, `_accountEmail` field should be changed to static.

For more info, you could refer to [Dependency Injection Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#registration)